# setVisibility(View.GONE) shrinking display size

Tags: java, android, xml

Android version 11.0.4

I am trying to use a `ListView` to display a series of elements with different types of information to display in the same list using a custom `ListAdapter`.

To make the same `ListAdapter` able to display different types of information I'm creating a custom XML template with all possible elements that I want to display and hiding the ones I don't want to show programmatically.

However, when I hide the extra elements I don't want to show the size of the view displaying them shrinks.

[When the extra elements are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ0GQ.png)

[When the extra elements are gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z4tF.png)

The code that hides the elements:

```
TextView catagory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
TextView time1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time1);
TextView time2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time2);
TextView location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);

View separator1 = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.separator_vertical1);
View separator2 = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.separator_horizontal1);
View separator3 = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.separator_vertical2);
View separator4 = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.separator_horizontal2);

catagory.setText(item.name);
Class type = item.getType();
if (EventItem.class.equals(type)) {
    time1.setText(String.valueOf(((EventItem)item).timeStart));
    time2.setText(String.valueOf(((EventItem)item).timeEnd));
    location.setText(((EventItem)item).location);
    description.setText(((EventItem)item).description);
} else if (TaskItem.class.equals(type)) {
    time1.setText(String.valueOf(((TaskItem)item).timeDue));
    description.setText(((TaskItem)item).description);
    //hide unused elements
    separator2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    location.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    separator3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    time2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if (ReminderItem.class.equals(type)) {
    time1.setText(String.valueOf(((ReminderItem)item).time));
    //hide unused elements
    separator2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    location.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    separator3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    time2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    separator4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if (SubjectItem.class.equals(type)) {
    description.setText(((SubjectItem)item).description);
} else if (NoteItem.class.equals(type)) {
    description.setText(((TaskItem)item).description);
    //hide unused elements
    separator1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    time1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    separator2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    location.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    separator3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    time2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if (ContactItem.class.equals(type)) {
    //hide unused elements
    separator1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    time1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    separator2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    location.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    separator3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    time2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

The XML template:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
    <View
            android:id="@+id/separator_vertical1"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/time1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time1"
            android:layout_width="94dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/title"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
    <View
            android:id="@+id/separator_horizontal1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/separator_horizontal1"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
    <View
            android:id="@+id/separator_vertical2"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/location"
            android:layout_below="@id/separator_horizontal1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time2"
            android:layout_width="94dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/location"
            android:layout_below="@id/separator_horizontal1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
    <View
            android:id="@+id/separator_horizontal2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/location"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/separator_horizontal2"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
```

The `ListView` the elements are displayed in:

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"

    android:id="@+id/text_overview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="8dp"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it working, not sure how but setting each element as visible before going into the if statements stoped the shrinking of the view window. It also solved the issue of some list items missing elements that shouldn't have been hidden. I can only assume some resources were being reused somewhere and arriving pre-hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is to use View.INVISIBLE

> However, when I hide the extra elements I don't want to show the size of the view displaying them shrinks.

**`View.GONE`**: This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

**`View.INVISIBLE`**: This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

Here's the link of [Documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: when using invisible https://i.imgur.com/20T4zK0.png happens which is not the effect I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use View.INVISIBLE which takes up space and invisible the view.
while you are using View.GONE which doesn't takes up space for the view and invisible the view.

For more description, you can go with:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility

Comment: I understand that, but the issue is that when using invisible the extra elements take up space in the list like shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/20T4zK0.png). The look of each element is how I want it to be with gone, but for some reason the space that displays the list shrinks and cuts off elements before they get to the bottom of the page.